# Downloading Stencil behind corporate proxy

Tags: javascript, git, npm, stenciljs

I'm trying to start my first Stencil project and am seeing this error:

```
 Cannot download "https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil- 
 component-starter/archive/master
 .zip"
 Check your internet connection

 Error: connect ETIMEDOUT"
```

I have both my git config and npm config http and https proxy settings correctly pointing to my proxy url but I'm still getting this error. Why?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same limitation at work.

Do a `curl -kvL`, that will give you an idea of what is actually blocked:

```
curl -kvL https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/releases/download/v1.9.1/gitea-1.9.1-windows-4.0-amd64.exe.xz
...
CONNECT github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com:443 HTTP/1.1
...
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

What is usually blocked in an enterprise environment is `s3.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I messed around with it for as long as I could and just switched over to using Lit.

Answer (score 1):

Can you curl the same zip directly through your proxy?

```
curl -x http://proxy_server:proxy_port --proxy-user username:password -L "https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter/archive/master.zip"
```

Comment: Didn't work. I just have to face the facts that my company blocks Github uploads/downloads. Thanks anyway.